# WPF selected value , displaymember path inconsistency with listbox and combo box

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a stored procedure called `DropDownIndividuals()` which was created using LINQ.
The stored procedure returns `FullName` and `Case_Number`. I want to set the `SelectedValuePath` equal to the `Case_Number` column in my stored procedure. This is how I did it for a listbox and it works.

```
private void listBox1_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e){
    using (ToolboxDataContext toolboxDB = new ToolboxDataContext())//this is linq in action
    {
         var x = toolboxDB.DropDownIndividuals().ToList();//convert to a list
         listBox1.ItemsSource = x;  //bind the data 
         listBox1.SelectedValuePath = "Case_Number";
         listBox1.DisplayMemberPath = "FullName";

         Console.WriteLine(listBox1.SelectedValue.ToString());
         //Result:it shows the case number of the person the user picks.
    }
}
```

Now I do the same thing for a dropdown combobox AND IT DOES NOT WORK.

```
private void individualDropDown_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    using (ToolboxDataContext toolbox = new ToolboxDataContext())
    {
        var individualDropDownBox = toolbox.DropDownIndividuals().ToList();
        individualDropDown.ItemsSource = individualDropDownBox;
        individualDropDown.DisplayMemberPath = "FullName";
        individualDropDown.SelectedValuePath = "Case_Number";
        Console.WriteLine(individualDropDown.SelectedValue.ToString());
    }
}
```

Why? How can I fix this?

Comment: "DOES NOT WORK" You can do better than that. What doesn't work? What did you expect to happen, and what happened instead? People will be more likely to help (and better able to help) if you explain the problem.

Comment: Ok, when I pick someone from the combo box it should display the case_number for example: The combo box has 2 values "Jay" and "Rodrigo". If I pick Jay it should display his case number in the console. Let say his case number is 54444.

Comment: what does it do instead?

Comment: It says object reference not set to an instance of an object for the line  Console.WriteLine(individualDropDown.SelectedValue.ToString());

Comment: Anyhows, it would suffice to know how to add a displaymemberpath and selectedvaluepath to a combobox and how to access the values in them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why so chaotic? You do not even set properties in the same order, *this* is equivalent:

```xml
<Grid Margin="5">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ListBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"
             Name="lbData" ItemsSource="{Binding DpData}"
             DisplayMemberPath="Name"
             SelectedValuePath="Id"/>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"
               Text="{Binding ElementName=lbData, Path=SelectedValue}"/>

    <ComboBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Top"
              Name="cbData" ItemsSource="{Binding DpData}"
              DisplayMemberPath="Name"
              SelectedValuePath="Id"/>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"
               Text="{Binding ElementName=cbData, Path=SelectedValue}"/>
</Grid>
```

[image: screenshot]

...and it displays the same ID as expected.

**Edit:** At startup the selected value of both controls is `null` by the way.

Comment: in the itemsource if I have a linq class called toolbox which has my storedprocedure called dropdownindividuals() do I put 
Name="lbData" ItemsSource="{Binding Toolbox}"    ??

Comment: That won't work, to bind to a set of objects which are retrieved via method-call you can use an [ObjectDataProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.objectdataprovider.aspx).

Comment: ok i guess I will research object data provider and see where that leads me. I dont see why I have to do it with xaml and I cant just bind the  individualDropDown.DisplayMemberPath = "FullName";directly from codebehind.

Comment: It should not make a difference really. This XAML probably just does not care if the value is `null` at any point. I only wanted to illustrate that i did not have any problems/could not see any difference so far. Why don't you just check for null before calling `ToString()`? (Edit: I just checked and both controls have `SelectedValue==null` at the beginning)

Comment: yes it would be null because u dont have the database connection to get the data from sql server

Comment: No, i do not get my data from a DataBase, it's just that by dafault no item is selected in either case.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, there is an inconsistency of sorts between the way that `SelectedValue` is treated for `ListBox` and `ComboBox`.  For `ListBox`, upon load, if it has the focus, the `SelectedValue` will correspond to the first item in the data source.  For `ComboBox` even if it has the focus and a data source supplies items, the default `SelectedValue` will be unset during the `Loaded` event handler.

This behavior is by design.  To make the `ComboBox` behave like the `ListBox` set `ComboBox.SelectedIndex` to `"0"` where you define the `ComboBox` in the XAML.

Comment: <ComboBox SelectedIndex="0"  Canvas.Left="296" Canvas.Top="6" Height="22" Name="individualDropDown" Width="170" Visibility="Hidden" DropDownOpened="individualDropDown_DropDownOpened" />
I still get object reference problem

Comment: Comment out the debug statement and just run the program.  Does the combo box select the first name?  Add a handler for `individualDropDown_SelectionChanged` to see the change happening.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
MetroAreaList metroAreaList = _presenter.GetMetroArea();
foreach (MetroArea metroArea in metroAreaList) {
    lstMetroArea.DisplayMemberPath = "Name";
    lstMetroArea.SelectedValuePath = "ID";
    lstMetroArea.Items.Add(metroArea);
}
```

It is working....

Answer (score 0):

Your class should be public:

```
public class Place
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Id { get; set; }
}
foreach (var y in Lists)
{
    listBox1.DisplayMemberPath = "Name";
    listBox1.SelectedValuePath = "Id";
    // Console.WriteLine(y.Case_Number.ToString());
    listBox1.Items.Add(y);
}
```